# Why do vim and less have such similar keybindings?

Tags: command-line, vim, less, history-of-ubuntu

Do they share code, or is that just a tradition? Are there any other programs with similar keybindings?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Short answer, common historical roots in `vi`. Their creators were both users of an earlier Unix program, `vi`.

Here is a rough diagram to put their initial release dates and influence in perspective:

```
vi 1976
 | \      more 1978
 |  \     /
 |   \   /
 |     v
 |   less 1983
 v
vim 1991
```

Sources:

- [vi, 1976](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi)
- [more, 1978](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_(command))
- [less, 1983](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html#history)
- [vim, 1991](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor))

### Vim

Vim, by Bram Moolenaar, is a [clone of the Unix program `vi`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)). From within vim you can look at the help intro: [`:help intro`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#intro), you see:

> Vim is a text editor which includes almost all the commands from the Unix program "Vi" and ...

### Less

Whereas the creator of `less`, Mark Nudelman explains on [his FAQ](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html#history):

> Back in 1983, I was working for a now-defunct company called
>   Integrated Office Systems. Some of our software ran on a Unix system
>   and produced enormous log files of its transactions. We wanted to be
>   able to search these log files for error messages. But the version of
>   "vi" we were using couldn't handle files larger than a certain size,
>   and our log files often exceeded that size. So we were forced to use
>   "more" to view the files. The problem was, once we found an error
>   message, what we really wanted to see was the transactions leading up
>   to the error; that is, the lines in the log file immediately before
>   the error message. But more didn't allow backward movement in the
>   file.

So he was already using `vi` and `more` when he created `less` to overcome the limitations of both `vi` and `more` at that time.

When you do `man less`, you see the connection to `vi`:

> Commands are based on both more and vi.

### Vim and Less

So `less` and `vim` seem to coincidentally have commands similar to each other, only because, those commands are actually based on `vi`, which can be seen as their common ancestor.

Comment: I suspected they have similar roots but how about authors ? Are the vi and less authors the same ?

Comment: @Serg Nope. `vi` was written Bill Joy, Vim by Bram Moolenaar, `less` by Mark Nudelman. As quoted above, the author says they first tried `vi`, but it couldn't handle the files, and then they tried `more`, which couldn't move back. So they wrote `less`. So, presumably, `vi` is the first option for them, and they are used to `vi`-like keybindings.

Comment: Also an addition to this: Because these small family of tools became quite popular and pretty  much the standards on a linux ecosystem more and more programs start turning these bindings in a tradition as they were well known to the community [here is a big list of vim inspired appplications](https://reversed.top/2016-08-13/big-list-of-vim-like-software/)